# Query doesn't execute when using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My first question on this forum.

For a while I'm trying to learn some basic Ajax, jQuery and Php. I want to make a 'Favorite' function where people can click on an icon. When this icon is clicked, there should be an Ajax function which links to the .php document, which then handles the query.

For some reason everything is working except that the query isn't executing (I believe).

Note that also my **FavoriteMovie.php** is requesting well. (Comes in 'Network' tab at Chrome).

Also my Ajax gives me a succes messages.

**Scripts.s**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.favorited').click(function () {

       SendFavorite();
    });
});

function SendFavorite()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/FavoriteMovie.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true
    })
    // using the done promise callback
        .done(function (data) {
          console.log(data);

        })

.fail(function() {
    console.log('Error!'); // This one isn't reached. Because its 'succeeded'.
});
}
```

**FavoriteMovie.php**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$return = [
    'success' => false,
    'message' => ''
];

    $db = openDatabaseConnection();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users_favorites SET (user_id, movie_id) VALUES (24, 1)";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

    $return['success'] = true;
    $return['message'] = 'Success!';

    echo json_encode($return);

?>
```

This is my Console: http://prntscr.com/gllrpx

This is my Network: http://prntscr.com/glm701

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What are you sending though? your data: is empty

Comment: By "your query isn't working", I'm going to guess it doesn't update the database. You'll need to show your PHP code for us to troubleshoot that.

Comment: Do not put your code in comments. Please update/edit your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: But you're sending anything to that page, so it doesn't actually run that page

Comment: Stupid question, how do I edit my question. Just new here.

Comment: Click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46245518/edit) link

Comment: Just added the remaining code. The HTML is just a simple div with classname '.favorited'.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. It's either `INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2)` or `INSERT INTO table column1 = value1, column2 = value2`. not both. Checking for mysql errors would have told you the query failed.

Comment: I've no idea where I was with my head. Doing some 'Update' and 'Insert' mix in one query. *Facepalm*.

Well, thanks, it's working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should read...

```
INSERT INTO users_favorites (user_id, movie_id) VALUES (24, 1)
```

Remove the SET